# Did Facebook Graph API completely block fetching event data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Before the latest updates which were made due to the Cambridge Analytica problem, I was able to get data for a facebook event (name, date, description, cover photo link, etc...) just by passing the event id to the graph API, now it's not working.

```
FacebookApiException: {"error":{"message":"Unsupported get request. Object with ID '**event-id**' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api","type":"GraphMethodException","code":100,"error_subcode":33,"fbtrace_id":"DzBRa9cQ385"}}
```

Did they completely block the ability to fetch event data, or is it still available in a different way and I can't seem to know what is it?

Comment: You are correct. Search Stackoverflow and you can see you are not the first one that asks. Your app needs to get approved and currently app review is paused

Comment: My app was approved, and it was working. As far as I know, Facebook isn't reviewing new apps, but the ones that previously existed are still working. @WizKid

Comment: No old apps are not working

Comment: Then, how is my bot still functioning and other features of the Graph API are still working?

Comment: Other stuff are working. Events are not working for anyone. Read the breaking changes https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

Comment: Mine isn't but maybe you've found a way. Have you renewd tokens, approved something ? I've gone through all the settings to save them, renew them, etc.  How many businesses rely on these data ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, events API endpoints were deprecated in recent changes, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/